# Put an ID on TextView

Tags: android

When I put an ID on my TextView, my App closes.

I could put id's on my MainActivity, but I have other actions, and it closes when I put an ID on something in the other XML file.

Maybe it's problem of my AndroidManifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="pk.Android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="ParcNet"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Parc_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical" 
                      android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView 
                  android:id="@+id/tv_capcalera_pagina_dos"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:text="Parcs"
                  android:textSize="23dp"
                  android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/textParc_Buscar"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="215px"  
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20px" />

            <Button
                   android:id="@+id/buttonParc_Buscar"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Buscar"
                   android:layout_marginTop="17px"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="5px" /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/buttonParc_Menu"
                android:text="Retrocedir"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

To fix this problem I had to clean the project to rebuild the resource files.

Comment: show the codes please

Comment: show the other xml code where you want to put the id of the TextView.Remove from the second activity : 
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
because you have have only one MAIN activity..

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to close your LinearLayout by adding

```
</LinearLayout>
```

at the end of XML layout file.

Comment: Here you have the complete xml i think is all ok, as i said buttons works perfectly.. if i take out the id from TextView i can go throw the 4 layouts i have but naw i wanted to put this id and i can't open de app if i put it

Comment: Perhaps try the solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470268/android-adding-id-to-layout-break-my-code

Comment: It stills No error, no log, it just breaks everything without registering any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical" 
                      android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TextView 
                  android:id="@+id/tv_capcalera_pagina_dos"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:text="Parcs"
                  android:textSize="23dp"
                  android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/textParc_Buscar"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="215px"  
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20px" />

            <Button
                   android:id="@+id/buttonParc_Buscar"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Buscar"
                   android:layout_marginTop="17px"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="5px" /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/buttonParc_Menu"
                android:text="Retrocedir"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When i put this id on my second activity my app closes, if i take out this id, i can go to this layout perfectly and push buttons, i have buttons on this xml with id's and i don't have any problem to swap layouts wiht them.

Answer (score -2):

Finally I solved the problem. To fix the problem i just make a cleen from the project, it was problem of the file R.java that don't generate well the ID's.